# Openquery procedure from linked server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I'm calling procedure from server B:

```
select * from openquery(A,'exec sp_qa2')
```

sp_qa2 in Server A is this:

```
use master
go
create procedure sp_qa2
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'USE [?];  EXEC    [dbo].[sp_qa1]'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql
end
```

and sp_qa1 in Server A is this:

```
create procedure sp_qa1
begin
declare @a int
end
```

This error is returning:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSforeach_worker, Line 102
>   [Batch Start Line 2] Invalid object name '#qtemp'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like `#qtemp` hasn't been created in `sp_MSforeach_worker`. Can you post code from this procedure where this error is occurring? Also, this procedure isn't mentioned anywhere in the code you have provided. How is it being executed?

Comment: That #qtemp table in sp_MSforeach_worker is system procedure, which everybody has. That is not something I've created.

Comment: So it is, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `RPC` and `RPC OUT` option of your Linked server is `TRUE`?

Also, you can directly execute the code without openquery like below:

```
EXEC [A].[database].[schema].sp_qa2
```

Comment: Yes, they are true. I know that I can execute it by providing whole 4 name. I want to do OPENQUERY because it is better in terms of performance

Comment: Are you getting same error by executing with the 4 part name?

Comment: OPENQUERY does not support multiple result sets whereas SP_MSForEachDB returns one result set per database - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1210374-1292-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you also can try use:

```
EXEC(@sql) AT [RemoteServer]
```